# Bootstrap Show LI side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I display LI.parent side by side?

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and my HTML is:

```
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">

<li class="item-001 dropdown parent">
    <a href="/abc">ABC</a>
    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="item-1">
            <a href="/abc/1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <a href="/abc/2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-3">
            <a href="/abc/3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-4">
            <a href="/abc/4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="item-002 dropdown parent">
    <a href="/abc">DEF</a>
    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="item-1">
            <a href="/def/1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <a href="/def/2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-3">
            <a href="/def/3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-4">
            <a href="/def/4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="item-003 dropdown parent">
    <a href="/abc">GHI</a>
    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="item-1">
            <a href="/ghi/1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <a href="/ghi/2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-3">
            <a href="/ghi/3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-4">
            <a href="/ghi/4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have `li` elements side by side, you simply need to use a left float in your CSS like so:

```
.dropdown {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If there are a different number of LIs within the dropdown-submenu, the layout looks strange though. See this http://jsfiddle.net/k9g76w57/